# How to replace a string between two words where each word in a different line by java

Tags: java, string

After reading my file.txt by java. How to replace a string between two words (`<change>` and `</change>`), where each word in a different line ?

Example:

```
enter random text blah blah <change> hello java 
</change> more random text
```

I need it like:

```
enter random text blah blah replaced more random text
```

I tried to do it with `Pattern p = Pattern.compile ...`, but failed.

Comment: Did you use a multi-line pattern?

Comment: Can you use `String.format()` ?

Comment: Take a look at LINE TERMINATORS section here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. This option lets you match line end in your regex: Pattern.compile("regex", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29    `String.format(text,replaceWith);` replaces occurence of `%1$s` in `text` by `replaceWith`

Answer (score -2):

Try this : `s.replaceAll("<c.*>.*<.*e>", "replaced")`

Change character `c`cand `e` accordingly. In this case your tag name is `<change>` so first and last chars are `c` and `e` respectively.

Comment: `I like  <cake>chocolate</cake> so <change> or <leave> this </leave> here </change>.`